# hover function--.making border-bottom during both hover and after click

Tags: jquery, click, hover, border

I have three  items: General, Secretary, and Treasurer.
I want to make it so that when i hover over the link, a border will appear under the text.
But i also want to make it so that after i click it, the border still stays.
and after the click, if i hover over another link, the border should appear as well
(eg i click on general, then a red border should stay; if i then hover over secretary, the red border stays, but a green border appears; if i then click on secretary, the red border goes away and the green border stays)

here is my js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var height = $(".content_box").height() - 50;
    $(".general_box").css("height","0");
    $(".general_box").css("border-bottom","4px solid white");

    $("#general_heading a")
        .hover(function(){
            $(this).css("border-bottom","4px solid rgb(230,0,0)");
            $("#secretary_heading a").css("border-bottom","4px solid white");
            $("#treasurer_heading a").css("border-bottom","4px solid white");
        },function(){
            $(this).css("border-bottom","4px solid white");
        })
        .click(function(){
            $(this).css("border-bottom","4px solid rgb(230,0,0)");
            $("#secretary_heading a").css("border-bottom","4px solid white");
            $("#treasurer_heading a").css("border-bottom","4px solid white");

            $("#secretary_box").stop(true).css("height","0");
            $("#treasurer_box").stop(true).css("height","0");
            $("#general_box").animate({height:height},2000,"easeOutBounce");
            $("#general_box ul").fadeIn(2000);
            $("#secretary_box ul").css("display","none");
            $("#treasurer_box ul").css("display","none");
        });

    $("#secretary_heading a")
        .hover(function(){
            $(this).css("border-bottom","4px solid rgb(0,180,0)");
            $("#treasurer_heading a").css("border-bottom","4px solid white");
            $("#general_heading a").css("border-bottom","4px solid white");
        },function(){
            $(this).css("border-bottom","4px solid white");
        })
        .click(function(){
            $(this).css("border-bottom","4px solid rgb(0,180,0)");
            $("#treasurer_heading a").css("border-bottom","4px solid white");
            $("#general_heading a").css("border-bottom","4px solid white");

            $("#general_box").stop(true).css("height","0");
            $("#treasurer_box").stop(true).css("height","0");
            $("#secretary_box").animate({height:height},2000,"easeOutBounce");
            $("#secretary_box ul").fadeIn(2000);
            $("#general_box ul").css("display","none");
            $("#treasurer_box ul").css("display","none");
        });

    $("#treasurer_heading a")
        .hover(function(){
            $(this).css("border-bottom","4px solid rgb(0,0,200)");
            $("#secretary_heading a").css("border-bottom","4px solid white");
            $("#general_heading a").css("border-bottom","4px solid white");
        },function(){
            $(this).css("border-bottom","4px solid white");
        })
        .click(function(){
            $(this).css("border-bottom","4px solid rgb(0,0,200)");
            $("#secretary_heading a").css("border-bottom","4px solid white");
            $("#general_heading a").css("border-bottom","4px solid white");

            $("#general_box").stop(true).css("height","0");
            $("#secretary_box").stop(true).css("height","0");
            $("#treasurer_box").animate({height:height},2000,"easeOutBounce");
            $("#treasurer_box ul").fadeIn(2000);
            $("#secretary_box ul").css("display","none");
            $("#general_box ul").css("display","none");
        });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USE THIS CODE - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pzrDr/)

js -

```
$('li').on('click',function(){
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

css -

```
li{
    float:left;
    list-style:none;
    padding: 3px 8px;
    background: #efefef;
    cursor: pointer;
}
li:hover, li.active{
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

html -

```
<ul>
    <li>Hello</li>
    <li>Hi</li>
    <li>Hey</li>
    <li>Welcome</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give a active and hover classes using jquery addClass() function. Then simply give css to these clasees in style. You can remove class using removeClass() function if your link is not active.